# Is it possible to proxy an interface with multiple methods going to different endpoints

Tags: proxy, apache-camel

I have an interface with methods foo() and bar() that I'd like to go to endpoints direct:foo and direct:bar.  In the proxy configuration you are only allowed to enter one endpoint and I have not found any way to get the name of the method called in code to be able to route based on that name.

Am I missing some document somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the info at http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html related to  'toD'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a Camel version > 2.15

Revert to  [old behaviour](https://camel.apache.org/using-camelproxy.html) which does not bind parameters to body and then you will have accesso to [BeanInvocation](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/bean/BeanInvocation.html#getMethod()) object that will tell you which method was called.

```
// Create Proxy
MyAuditService service = new ProxyBuilder(context)
     .endpoint("direct:analyzeMethodCall")  // dispatcher endpoint
     .binding(false)  // false: gives you BeanInvocation, true gives you parameter
     .build(MyAuditService.class);
```

Then in your route from `direct:analyzeMethodCall` use a Processor to analyze the BeanInvocation object and call `direct:foo` or `direct:bar`. You must set the body explicitly.

Comment: Cool.  I'll give that a try.  I've been using the XML method for defining the proxy and it looks like there is a "binding" attribute to use.